# Distinguishing React propTypes

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Apparently, I need to remove the warnings in ESLint

```
'campaignTypesResult' is missing in props validation      react/prop-types
'campaignTypesResult.map' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
'statusesResult' is missing in props validation           react/prop-types
'statusesResult.map' is missing in props validation       react/prop-types
'campaignsActions' is missing in props validation                 react/prop-types
'campaignsActions.createCampaign' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
```

`campaignTypesResult`, and `statusesResult` are the array initialized in react-redux.

`campaignsActions` is the action for campaign in react-redux.

I assume that `campaignTypesResult` is `propType.array` and `campaignsActions` `propType.function`.

What is the correct validation for each?

Comment: Can you please post your code for reducer and actions

Comment: It's just the same with other react-redux code. My code for reducer includes the initalState, and other reducers. Actions include CRUD function that calls the API. I just need to know what is the proper validation for campaignsActions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, it seems that actions is an 'object', and my initial state is 'array'. Having action as a 'function' writes an error in the console saying that action is indeed an 'object'.

```
AddCampaignPage.propTypes = {
    statusesActions: PropTypes.object,
    campaignTypesActions: PropTypes.object,
    campaignsActions: PropTypes.object,
    campaignTypesResult: PropTypes.array,
    statusesResult: PropTypes.array
};
```